# Farsi in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, farsi

I want to add some farsi data into a table in mongoDB, but every character has been showed as a unknown character. 
how to add farsi data fields into a collection (table) in mongoDB database?

Comment: You need to make sure your data is utf8 on the way in and you're correctly displaying utf8 after you get it out. MongoDB itself defaults to utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BSON` can only be encoded in `UTF-8`! So by default Mongodb stores data in UTF-8.

how do you store data in your Mongo? you've to look for the problem over there!

Comment: I'm new with mongoDB and just wanted to add some farsi data collections into mongoDB from command line.

Comment: what's your OS? as you may know, Windows cmd doesn't support UTF-8! if you're using linux, you're gonna see the characters, but they're disconnected!

Comment: if you only want to play with Mongodb, then use `3T MongoChef`!